# Premade masteries or choose on the fly?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm going to end this season in the gold division and I try to imporve my playstyle constantly. I often see / hear ppl claiming that you shouldn't have prefilled masteries but adapt them before every game. Does this have such a high impact on the game? Is there a sort of cheat sheet for when I should skill which tree?

Comment: I have 19 pages that I use for specific champions in specific roles. Then I have one page that I constantly change for situations that don't fit those pages.

Comment: Also, ever seen someone with no keystone? This is generally because of people changing their masteries and saving it in the last few seconds of lobby, which results in the mastery page not being saved and thus they go into the game with nothing. If you aren't confident in picking your masteries quickly, don't do it. Just stick with your premade pages. Having just okay masteries for your champ may not be better than having super good masteries adjusted for your champ and the enemy team comp but it sure is better than having none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many pros/high elo players adjust their masteries every game based on individual matchups in that game so that they get the most beneficial stats they can from masteries. For example, a mid laner may have a generic mid lane mastery page in which they take 2 points in Meditation (mana regen) and 3 points in Merciless (bonus damage to champions below 40% hp). This may be perfectly fine for someone like Ahri, but if you are instead playing Zed, it would be better to take the two points in Meditation and put them into Merciless, as Zed does not benefit from mana regen.

Also, in the case of marksmen, some marksmen do well with thunderlord's decree, while others like Jhin benefit more from Deathfire Touch. Also, if you are in a matchup against a heavy poke lane, it may be better to take Wardlord's Bloodlust to avoid being pushed out of lane as easily.

**TL:DR** It is fine to have premade mastery pages to save time when setting them up, but if you want to optimize you stats gained from them, you should always try and fine tune them each match based on the champions you are facing.

Comment: For most ADC's, I would recommend **Fervor of Battle** as well. This is a must-have for long-range, poking ADC's that don't rely on go-ins, and overall my favourite keystone on marksmen.

Answer (score 4):

Adapting for each game is better, but not necessary. Similar to runes, your masteries help affect your early game, which can determine the state of the game.

Adapting them to your enemies gives you the benefits of more tanky stats, damage or utility depending on your matchup or team composition. For example, if you are against an opponent that you can trade or harass a lot, choosing Thunderlord's may be good as it gives you more damage in the exchange. On the other end of that trade, if you have a shield or heal ability, Windspeaker's Blessing can help you recover health or mitigate damage.

If you are interested in what others use, you could check out [Champion.GG](http://champion.gg). There you can look at specific champions, most taken masteries, masteries with highest win rate, and item builds.

Answer (score 1):

As with anything in LoL, strategy varies from person to person. Some people like to spec their mastery trees from scratch at the beginning of each game, and others like to have a couple pre-filled pages that they can use. There are benefits and drawbacks to each.

Keystone masteries (the final tier in any given mastery tree) are the most important and usually define an overarching playstyle for the champion you're playing. (For example, Thunderlord's Decree is good for a champions that rely on combos since it gives them a small burst of damage after 3 abilities.) However, there are other masteries that can also heavily affect how you play, such as the one that increases your cooldown reduction cap. Filling out each page from scratch allows for more customization in your masteries, and thus more customization of how you want to play.

Pre-filled mastery pages are meant to be an easy-access guideline for a certain playstyle. If you notice you enjoy playing marksmen (which typically use a 18-12-0 mastery setup), it would make sense to fill in your most common choices and save a page. That way, during champion select, you can look at the choices you've already made and adjust based on the enemy team, as opposed to hastily putting together a page from scratch every time. This is the method I would recommend.

As for which masteries you should take on which champion... well, that's part of the whole idea behind strategy. Generally speaking, tanks go 0-12-18, assassins go 12-18-0, and marksmen go 18-12-0. However, there are exceptions to this rule, depending on what the meta is. The best way to figure out what would work the best for a given champion is to do some research - what do guides say? What does a streamer (who mains that champion) choose? Remember to critically analyze why these resources are recommending certain choices, because if you don't understand *why* there's not a whole lot of point in following the choices blindly.